# How to set TextFormField‘s text‘s left margin（Not Label） Flutter

Tags: flutter, textformfield

My App is using TextFormField, but TextFormField's **text's** left margin is as same as the **label**, now I have a demand, **text's** left margin is bigger than **label**. How to resolve this issue. Thx.

Ex:[TextFormField's title and text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YB5E6.png)

Comment: Do you want to add a margin for the title of your text field?

Comment: yep，but if I set InputDecoration's contentPadding, the title and the text is all affected.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
TextFormField(
    decoration: InputDecoration(
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
            horizontal: YOUR_PREFERRED_PADDING,
            vertical: 13.0,
        ),
    ),
),
```

Comment: Thx for your reply, but if I set the padding of widget, the text and label of the TextFormField is all padding to the left.
Now I want to set the text's left Padding only,
Thank U!

Comment: Either use the property `isDense: true` or consider removing the label by replacing it with a `Text` widget

Answer (score 0):

you can opt EdgeInsets (symetrics, all,only,....) bro!

Comment: Now I set the contentPadding below, but the title and the text is all affected.

    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(
  left: AppTheme.padding5,
  top: 0,
  bottom: 0,
),